# Get input's name angularjs

Tags: angularjs

An API I am using requires data to be sent via ajax with Name, Value pairs.  The Name can have spaces and other characters unlike the Model.

So the model as it has to be alphanumeric characters isn't a direct representation of the name.  Eg:
Name, Model, Value

Has GST (yes/no), stepTwo.has_gst_yes_no, 1

so when I:

```
 console.log($scope.stepTwo)
 //I have:
 //has_gst_yes_no=1
```

This is great, but how can I get the input name's as well  as I will need to use this as the key when sending to the API.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sounds like you want to override angular's default request tranform function. This post explains in full: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: Thanks, but don't think that answers my questions.

Comment: From what you write I guess Name should be part of the model, and should have nothing to do with bindings. You should have models like `$scope.foo = { name:"foo", model: "foo", value: "1" }` and bind like `ng-model="foo.value"`. Other option is to extend `ngModel` directive to read name from `name` HTML attriubute and attach it to data.

Comment: when you use angular to connect with the API, for sending your model\command to some action in your API you do not need to have inputs name, for that just send your model which you create it in the angular controller.

Comment: Wait, so your API accepts "Has GST (yes/no)" as the key in your key/value pair?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the form directive in angular:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

now the form object generated has the name of the input. But I don't think that angular accepts such key/value pairs.

You can do a mapping in a function. There you can define such key/value pairs like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj["this is property"] = "foo";
```